# Flutter: Unable to align TextButton.icon() widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter. I'm trying to figure out how to align my textbutton.icon() widgets to the rightmost as shown in image below [image]

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: <Widget>[
      Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: TextButton.icon(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              foregroundColor:
              MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red[200]),
            ),
            onPressed: delete,
            label: Text('Unfavorite'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.heart_broken),
          ),),

      ),
```

I tried to use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` but it still doesn't align that well. Any help is appreciated

Comment: in flutter the parent is setting the position of children, so you need to put a snippet of code for the whole widget so we can help

Comment: while you add the snippet so we can help, check this, it will be so worthful to understand https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints

Comment: if the above "Column" widget in "Row" then wrap "Column" with "Expanded" to occupy the remaining space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the picture and the column with 2 icons as children of a `Row` and set the row property `mainAxisAlignment` as `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    ExamplePhoto(),
    Column(
      children: [
        ExampleIcon(),
        ExampleIcon(),
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```